# Prove that $f(x)=|x-3|$ is continuous at $x=3$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity

Please check my proof :)

First we must prove $\lim_{x \to 3 } |x-3|=0$

Suppose we are give $\delta >0$ we must find $\delta $

such that $0<|x-3|<\delta \rightarrow |x-3|<\epsilon $

Choose $\delta = \epsilon $

For $x$ is real number

$$0<|x-3|<\delta \rightarrow |f(3)-3|=|3-3|=0<\delta =\epsilon $$

Then limit equal $0$

Second we prove $f(3)=0$
$$|x-3|\rightarrow |3-3|=0$$

Therefore it continuous at $x= 3$

Comment: In your line $0<|x-3|<\delta \rightarrow |f(3)-3|=|3-3|=0<\delta =\epsilon$, there's something funny going on. It's supposed to be "$0<|x-3|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(3)|<\epsilon$", and then you need to prove that this is in fact true. It's not difficult, but it needs to be done correctly. Also, we usually use $0\leq|x-3|<\delta$, or just $|x-3|<\delta$ instead, but you check $f(3)$ specifically afterwards, so that's not wrong. Just a bit unusual to me.

Comment: $|f(3) -3| = 3 $ since $f(3) = 0$, how did you get $|f(3) -3| = 0 $?

Comment: opp I miscalculated -*-

Comment: @I post  a  solution for your additional references. :D

Comment: @juniven Thank  ^ ^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

- $$\forall x>3\;\; f(x)=x-3 \implies $$

$$\lim_{x\to 3^+} f(x)=0$$

- $$\forall x<3 \;\;f(x)=-x+3 \implies$$

$$\lim_{x\to 3^-} f(x)=0$$

- $$f(3)=0$$

So, $f$ is continuous at $x=3$.

Answer (score 0):

We need to recall the following result.

**Result.** $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists if and only if both the limits $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a^-}f(x)$ exist and are equal. In this case,
$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to a^-}f(x).$$

In your problem, we have $f(x)=|x-3|$. Now,
$$\lim_{x\to 3^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 3^+}|x-3|=\lim_{x\to 3^+}(x-3)=0$$
and
$$\lim_{x\to 3^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 3^-}|x-3|=\lim_{x\to 3^-}(3-x)=0.$$
Applying the result, we get 
$$\lim_{x\to 3}f(x)=0=f(0)$$
which shows that $f$ is continuous at $x=3$.